# update bind with static IP

Tags: linux, bind, dhcp

with dynamic pc, the log is:

```
dhcpd[4574]: Added new forward map from test00.example.com. to 192.168.1.78
dhcpd[4574]: Added reverse map from 78.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. to test00.example.com.
```

with static IP, the log is:

```
dhcpd[4574]: DHCPDISCOVER from c8:d3:a3:34:d1:1d (dlinkrouter) via enp2s0
dhcpd[4574]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.51 to c8:d3:a3:34:d1:1d (dlinkrouter) via enp2s0
dhcpd[4574]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.51 (192.168.1.100) from c8:d3:a3:34:d1:1d (dlinkrouter) via enp2s0
dhcpd[4574]: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.51 to c8:d3:a3:34:d1:1d (dlinkrouter) via enp2s0
```

Is it possible update forward and reverse map of bind also with static IP?

```
cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

authoritative;
ddns-updates on;
ddns-update-style interim;
update-static-leases on;
ddns-domainname "example.com.";
ddns-rev-domainname "in-addr.arpa.";
allow client-updates;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

log-facility local7;

include "/etc/dhcp/example.com.key";

zone example.com. {
  primary 192.168.1.101;
  key rndc-key;
}

zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. {
  primary 192.168.1.101;
  key rndc-key;
}

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.1.50 192.168.1.90;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
        option netbios-name-servers 192.168.1.100;
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.101, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
        option routers 192.168.1.100;
        option domain-search "example.com";
        default-lease-time 600;
        max-lease-time 7200;
}
```

Comment: If the IP is static, why not putting it once and forever in the zone file?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment you likely should put the mapping in the zone. If you insist on DHCP server adding the mapping for static lease you have to specifically enable it with:

```
update-static-leases            true;
```

in your dhcpd.conf file.

Please also note that if your dhcp client does not send fqdn.fqdn option then you may have to include ddns-hostname in your host declaration.